# SQL Server 2008: DROP PROCEDURE error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssms-2014

I try to execute this command:

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.njams_test_sql_2.[PROC_CHECK_TRACE_SETTINGS]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
   DROP PROCEDURE dbo.njams_test_sql_2.[PROC_CHECK_TRACE_SETTINGS]
GO
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Msg 166, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   'DROP PROCEDURE' does not allow specifying the database name as a prefix to the object name

What I'm trying to do is to delete all objects in a database, so that the database is empty. I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Management Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error clearly says - you **cannot** use the database name as a prefix in a `DROP PROCEDURE`.

You need to make sure you're connected to the *correct* database and then you need to execute

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.njams_test_sql_2.[PROC_CHECK_TRACE_SETTINGS]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
   DROP PROCEDURE [PROC_CHECK_TRACE_SETTINGS]
GO
```

Comment: You actually **can** use the database, but he put it in wrong order. The correct order is: 1. database, 2. schema, 3. procedure name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the order of database name and schema.

This is wrong:

```
DROP PROCEDURE dbo.njams_test_sql_2.[PROC_CHECK_TRACE_SETTINGS]
```

This is correct:

```
DROP PROCEDURE njams_test_sql_2.dbo.[PROC_CHECK_TRACE_SETTINGS]
```

Or, you can just leave them away. Then the current database and the default schema (most likely `dbo`) are used:

```
DROP PROCEDURE [PROC_CHECK_TRACE_SETTINGS]
```